# c# : error appearing on foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the error message on this class. It says that cannot convert type 'char' to "string".

this is code on the main for the project:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            translate t = new translate();
            string txt = TextBox1.Text;
            string[] split = txt.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });

            foreach (string s in split)
            {

                if (s.Trim() != " ")
                    Label1.Text += s +"\n";
                t.makeWrd(s);   
            }

        }
```

and this is the class code
class:
public string[] word;

```
    public string makeWrd(string word)
    {

         var d = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {{"blue","biru"},
        {"red","merah"},
        {"green","hijau"},
        {"purple","gadung"}
        };
        foreach(string val in word) //<---the error appears here
        {
            string ja;
            if(d.TryGetValue(val, out ja))
            {
                return ja;
            }
        }

    }
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: what do you mean by `foreach(string val in word)` isnt's `word` already a single string?

Comment: When you enumerate a string: `(... in word)`, then you get chars.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over each character in `word`. Hence the error you get.

The `foreach` doesn't seem to have a purpose here. Try to remove it.

```
public string makeWrd(string word)
{

     var d = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {{"blue","biru"},
    {"red","merah"},
    {"green","hijau"},
    {"purple","gadung"}
    };

    string ja;
    if(d.TryGetValue(word, out ja))
    {
        return ja;
    }

}
```

Also, the `if (s.Trim()!= " ")` will always be `true`. Did you mean to use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))`?

Comment: @jenan: need more help?

Comment: Also, the if (s.Trim()!= " ") = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))

for the program above I wanted to key in an array of strings which will be send to the class program, where it will be compare to the key in the dictionary, and print out the dictionary values.